# Projection of a vector being spanned

Tags: vectors, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

Find the Projection of [2,4,1,3] on to W spanned by {[.7,.1,.7,.1],[.7,.1,-.7,-.1]}.

What would be the equation to start the process?

Is it (((y*v1)/v1*v1))*v1)+ (((y*v2)/v2*v2))*v2)

Comment: $(u_1)^2$ makes no sense if $u_1$ is a vector. Do you mean the dot product of $u_1$ with itself?

Comment: If that makes more sense then yes

Comment: I would point out that a vector and its projection are rarely the same so the second equation is unlikely to be what you're look for.

Comment: Would the other equation work to help me solve the question?

Comment: Yes it would. The first part is the projection onto the span of $u_1$ and the second part is the projection onto the span of $u_2$. When you add them together they are the projection into the plan spanned by $u_1$ and $u_2$. You can generalize this to $n$-dimension in this way so if you can get this down you've got the general idea.

Comment: Alright thank you!

Comment: If you know is the projection just 2.8 and .8?

Comment: I haven't actually used decimal notation for a many years. It's more common in the sciences than mathematics.

Comment: @CyclotomicField It’s important to point out that adding up the individual projections only works if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are orthogonal, which they are in this question.

Answer (score 1):

$ V_{0} = s \cdot [0.7, 0.1,0.7, 0.1] + t \cdot[0.7,0.1,-0,7,-0.1] $

$ V-V_{0} \perp [0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1], \ \ V- V_{0} \perp [0.7,0.1,-0.7,-0.1] $

Find  $ s, t. $

or

Gramm-Schmidt ortogonalization.

Comment: I got s and t as 2.8 and .8. Do I multiple that answer by the spanned vectors and then subtract that answer from  2,4,1,3?

Comment: What for ? V_{0} for s = 2,8 and t = 0,8  is projection for [ 2,4,1,3].